# Ambiguous overloaded call error in D7, works in XE7

Tags: delphi

I have a code with overloaded functions, one of them is class method, the other one is object method. Works fine under XE7, tried to implement the same code under D7, getting a compiler error, have no clue why.

> [Error] testform.pas(23): Ambiguous overloaded call to 'OpenForm'**

```pascal
unit testform;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Contnrs;

type
  TFrmBase = class(TForm)
  public
    class function Test: TModalResult; overload;
    class function OpenForm(AParamNames: array of string; AParamValues: array of Variant): TModalResult; overload;

    function OpenForm(AClassName: String; AParamNames: array of string; AParamValues: array of Variant): TModalResult; overload;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

class function TFrmBase.Test: TModalResult;
begin
  // here comes the error, tried without "TFrmBase.", same result
  Result := TFrmBase.OpenForm([], []);
end;

class function TFrmBase.OpenForm(AParamNames: array of string; AParamValues: array of Variant): TModalResult;
begin
  // do nothing
end;

function TFrmBase.OpenForm(AClassName: String; AParamNames: array of string; AParamValues: array of Variant): TModalResult;
begin
  // do nothing
end;

end.
```

Strangely (for me at least) if I remove the `AParamValues: array of Variant` code, it can be compiled just fine.

**Why is this one not working under D7? What should I fix here?** Probably I am missing something obvious.

Comment: It works in XE7 because the compiler has been improved since D7, and the recent version understands the code better. It's not unusual for code not to work in older versions that works in newer ones. Berlin can recognize the difference between an overloaded function that uses TDateTime and one that uses Double, while D2007 cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to make your code like the following

```
class function TFrmBase.Test: TModalResult;
var
  StrArr : array of string;
  VarArr : array of Variant;
begin
  //Fill your arrays here
  Result := TFrmBase.OpenForm(StrArr, VarArr);
end;
```

Comment: thanks, its working fine! do you what is the reason of this behaviour?

Comment: @tcxbalage: It works because it makes the call non-ambiguous; the compiler can tell the type based on the variable declarations.